# MySQL calculating differences between rows and write result to a column?

Tags: mysql

I have a problem which I can't solve, and really need your help!

I have to following table;

```
mysql> describe inactivitytmp;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ 
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra | 
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ 
| user_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| start_ts | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| end_ts   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       | 
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ 
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Table contains: user numeric, start/end unix timestamp. Data below is just to show you what it looks like:

```
user_id;  start_ts;   end_ts;
1            150000    150010
1            160011    160050
1            160100    160200
2            150011    150023
2            155001    155055
2            160001    160500
3            159001    159550
```

I want to calculate a new column called diff, which is the difference between start (row x+1) - stop (row x). If row x+1 is a different user than row x, then diff=0

So the result I'm looking for is:

```
user start   stop  diff
1   150000 150010  160011-150010=10001
1   160011 160050  160100-160050
1   160100 160200  0 (new user on next row)
2   150011 150023  155001-150023
2   155001 155055  160001-155055
2   160001 160500  0 (new user on next row)
3   159001 159550  and so on..
```

After a previous question here at Stackowerflow, and a lot of help from @fancyPants, I use the following code to add the column, and write the calculate result to the new column;

```
ALTER TABLE inactivitytmp add column diff int;

UPDATE inactivitytmp
JOIN (
SELECT inactivitytmp.*
 , if(@prev_user_id = `user_id`, (`end_ts` - @prev) * -1, 0) as diff2
 , @prev := `start_ts`
 , @prev_user_id := `user_id`
FROM inactivitytmp
 , (
SELECT @prev := null, @prev_user_id := null) var_int
ORDER BY `user_id`, `start_ts` DESC ) query_alias
ON inactivitytmp.user_id=query_alias.user_id AND inactivitytmp.start_ts=query_alias.start_ts AND inactivitytmp.end_ts=query_alias.end_ts
SET inactivitytmp.diff=query_alias.diff2;
```

Problem is this error message which I can't understand:

```
ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`database`.`inactivitytmp`.`end_ts` - (@`prev`))'
```

Any help will be appriciated!

Åke

Comment: One of the values probably calculated a negative number. Because you have the term `UNSIGNED` in there, that column only accepts values 0 or greater. Define that column without `UNSIGNED` (you'd want `SIGNED`) and see if that runs--then debug to eliminate negative values and change it back if you want.

Comment: But how do i create a SIGNED column? Tried the ALTER TABLE command. both with and without the SIGNED option. With the SIGNED option: column type is int(10). Without the SIGNED option: column type int(10) UNSIGNED ?!?!

Comment: What command are you running and what error message are you getting?  If you are changing a column that is referenced by a foreign key (such as a primary key) you may need to recreate any foreign keys.

Comment: I don't know what the problem was, or how I solved it. But it worked when I ran the update query, right after starting the mysql prompt.. :s